# define a path at export and store it in a variable

Tags: filemaker

I want to export some data from Filemaker. Is there a posibility to start a script with an export dialog were the user defines the export location and store this path in a variable so that the user does not have to define the location for following export scripts?

Thanks for your help!
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use a FileMaker plugin, the free BaseElements plugin has a function called BE_SelectFolder(prompt) which opens an open/save dialog, allows the user to select a folder, and returns the location of the folder as a string. So you'd define two variables

```
Set Variable [$thePath; value: “BE_SelectFolder("Please choose a folder:")”]
Set Variable [$theRef; value: “"filemac:" & $thePath & "/exportfile.fmp12"”]
```

(that's for Mac, you'd need to adjust the second variable calc for Windows) and then use $theRef as the file reference to save the exports to.

BaseElements is available from http://www.goya.com.au/baseelements/plugin. It's got a lot of other useful functions besides, it's worth checking out.

Comment: Hey Raymond, thanks for the cue. I just tested the plugin. I only have the problem, that I get the path without the Volume. So instead of "/Macintosh HD/Users/user/somefile/", I get "/Users/user/somefile/". How do I get the full path?

Comment: Ok, I just found out, that FileVault is the problem.

Comment: And there is also a solution to it: http://www.goya.com.au/category/blogtags/file-paths

Answer (score 2):

There is no FileMaker built-in functionality to return the file path for the exported file.

If the user runs the same export twice in a row, the folder selection dialogue will open at the same location. I suspect this is not what you need.

The easiest way to work around the problem is to use AppleScript on a Mac or VBScript on PC to popup a folder select dialogue, return it back to FileMaker and store in a variable. The rest is down to your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

New in FileMaker 14, from May 2015, in the "Miscellaneus script Step" you may find "[Get Directory](https://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.35.151.html#1184903)" which is the right one for your question.

His purpose is described as "Sets a variable to the fully qualified path of a specified folder."

You may also create a new folder, in case of needs, if "Allow Folder Creation" parameter is set.

Note: it is not compatible with FileMaker Go while, instead, you may use it for a RunTime distribution.